# Here is a method allows forward declarations in python. Is there any reason this should not work in larger cases?

Tags: python, forward-declaration

This works in this small example.
Is there anything wrong with the approach that I am missing?

Description an initial version of class base is defined so
that subclass1 which extends base will parse without error.
After the definition of subclass1, I redefine class base.
The main function creates an instance of subclass1 and the message from the print()
statements in the second definition of base, is printed on the console.

```
class base():
    '''
    The initial 'forward' def of base that allows subclass1 to parse without error.
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        print('original base called')

class subclass1(base):
    '''
    The definition of a class that subclasses base.
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        base.__init__(self)
        print('subclass1 init')

class base():
    '''
    The real definition of  class base that will appear further down in the module.
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        print('2nd def of base called')


''' Create a subclass object to see which definition of base is used. '''
n= subclass1()
'''The message '2nd def of base called' will be printed'''
```

Comment: This isn't a forward declaration, it's just how names are resolved. You didn't change which class `base` refers to in the declaration `class subclass1(base):`, you just changed which class `base` refers to in the *statement* `base.__init__(self)`. If you wrote this properly as `super().__init__()` then you would see `original base called`.

Comment: Note that your subclass does not inherit any members from your second base class; you just called its `__init__` method on an object which is not an instance of that class, and Python doesn't stop you from doing that.

Comment: second `base` seems useless - you could define all in first `base`. Why do you really need it? Maybe there are better methods then inheritance. Maybe you should send `base` to `subclass` as parameter and use it as inner object - `subclass1( base() )` and `self.inner_base = base_instance`